# Is there a low level alternative for bpy.ops.object.origin_set()

Tags: python, scripting, operator

When i want to move the Origin of an object by script, then i can do this as follows:

```
my_location   = [0,0,0]
active        = scene.objects.active
cursor        = scene.cursor_location.copy()

scene.objects.active  = obj
scene.cursor_location = my_location

bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR')

scene.cursor_location = cursor
scene.objects.active = active
```

Is there an efficient alternative which works without need to backup/restore the active object and the current cursor location ? If not, is it missing or is there a reason ?

Comment: WARNING: in Blender 1.79 this operator (origin_set()) works on **all the selected objects**, and not on the **active** object. Thus you need to store the collection of the selected objects, you need to deselect all (`bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')` ) and you need to set `obj.selected = True`. And afterwards, you need to iterate over your stored previous selection and restore the selected state

Answer (score 7):

Set the object location to the target location and translate the mesh vertices in the reverse direction (the negated vector of the difference between start location and target location of the origin = start minus target).

Note that [Mesh.transform()](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html?highlight=bpy.types.mesh.transform#bpy.types.Mesh.transform) is not supported in *Edit Mode*, you need to use a wrapped BMesh instead.

If you use blender 2.79 change `bpy.context.scene.cursor.location` to `bpy.context.scene.cursor_location`

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix

ob = bpy.context.object
cursor_world_loc = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location
cursor_local_loc = ob.matrix_world.inverted() @ cursor_world_loc

mat = Matrix.Translation(-cursor_local_loc)

me = ob.data
if me.is_editmode:
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
    bm.transform(mat)
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, False, False)
else:
    me.transform(mat)

me.update()

ob.matrix_world.translation = cursor_world_loc
```

Comment: @Gaia, you would need to make some tweaks for non-mesh objects. (e.g Curves and Armatures). Namely update() and conversion to bmesh.

Comment: This is only for mesh Objects. Would it make sense to propose a general function? Something similar to bpy.context.object.transform_origin(location,type) with type like what the operator has ?