# Translate object using lowest Z value python

Tags: python

I have an object located in the origin (0,0,0). I wonder how I can translate it along the z-axis where the lowest -z value of the object will be translated to z value 0 as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Loop over the vertices, find the one with the lowest z value, move the object up -whatever_the_previous_got_you :-) I'll post an answer in a few...

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42110/15543 in that it moves the origin to bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple script that accomplishes this...let me know if you have any questions.

```
import bpy

# get a reference to the active object
obj = bpy.context.object

# get the minimum z-value of all vertices after converting to global transform
lowest_pt = min([(obj.matrix_world * v.co).z for v in obj.data.vertices])

# transform the object
obj.location.z -= lowest_pt
```

Note

For 2.8 replace `*` with `@` for matrix multiplication.

```
lowest_pt = min([(obj.matrix_world @ v.co).z for v in obj.data.vertices])
```

Comment: Can also find the lowestZ in one line instead of a loop thus:
`lowestZ = min( [ ( obj.matrix_world * v.co ).z for v in obj.data.vertices ] )`

Comment: Adding object location to local vert coordinate is not converting to global location.  See comment above.

Comment: @TLousky Thanks! Your method also works correctly with rotation and scale that I wasn't thinking about when I posted originally. I have edited my answer to include this technique...

Comment: @batFINGER I was fooled into thinking this b/c I was not using a rotated or scaled object.

Comment: @pycoder what if the object was an armature? It doesn't work in that case as this solution only works for mesh as it uses the mesh vertices

Comment: @Tak That's a completely different problem, and something that I can't really think of a good reason to need off the top of my head. Would you be calculating based on the center of bones? The heads and tails? I think this would be better suited for a different question that explains these things clearly and gives an example of when you may want to use it.

Comment: @pycoder http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74936/move-object-without-changing-origin

Comment: The line 7 doesn't work in Blender 2.8: TypeError: Element-wise multiplication: not supported between 'Matrix' and 'Vector' types

What should we write instead? Thank you.

Comment: @DanylBekhoucha You should ask that as a separate question if you need an answer. I've not looked into porting my add-ons to Blender 2.8 yet, so I don't know off the top of my head.