# Object Transform Origin to Geometry Floor

Tags: modeling, origin

I have about 400 different Plant models. I need the origin to be at the very bottom of the plant so I can plant them at the correct height when I export them to Unity. Is there a faster way to do this than:

1. Snap cursor to Selected
2. Set 3D Cursor Location Z to 0
3. Object transform origin to 3D Cursor

Comment: If you are after a scripting solution, and if each plant model is one mesh,  could alter the [script here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73698/translate-object-using-lowest-z-value-python/73702).   There are also a number of align addons.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enable the **[align tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.91/addons/object/align_tools.html)** Add-On.

[image]
In the 3D Viewport select your objects, open the Sidebar (<kbd>N</kbd>)

Go to the *Item* tab.

In  *Align Tools* > *Advanced Align Operations*, click on the ***Advanced*** button.

On the bottom left of the viewport window the Align operators control will open.

Set the Operator to ***Pivot*** mode.

Enable ***Active too***, ***Self*** and ***Min***

Then  set the ***Axis*** you are aligning, in this case it should be **$Z$**

[image]

Then your objects origins are at the bottom.

For older versions of Blender the interface looks like this:

[image]

Comment: "404 - Cannot find file" Download link is not working

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42110/34004 This script worked. But I'm still interested in your tool, if you know a working link...

Comment: Changed the link based on that thread:https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?256114-Add-on-Advanced-align-tools&p=2857213&viewfull=1#post2857213

Comment: how do I get this thing to work now?

Comment: This is now included in Blender as an add-on.