# Translate object using lowest Z value with Python in Blender 2.8

Tags: python

This question shows how to move the lowest vertex of a mesh on the grid, but the script given only works in versions before Blender 2.8: [Translate object using lowest Z value python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73698/translate-object-using-lowest-z-value-python)

Here is the script given:

```
import bpy

# get a reference to the active object
obj = bpy.context.object

# get the minimum z-value of all vertices after converting to global transform
lowest_pt = min([(obj.matrix_world * v.co).z for v in obj.data.vertices])

# transform the object
obj.location.z -= lowest_pt
```

What is the version of this script for Blender 2.8?

Note: I have intentionally copied a similar title so the users can find the Blender 2.8 version more easily.

Comment: For 2.8 replace `*` with `@` for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Edited original q with this info.  I see in comments  it was suggested to ask  a new question... I'm not so sure that each question needing this simple change need be a new question.  If you agree consider removing.

Comment: @batFINGER I'm not sure about that...if the original answer came from someone who isn't keeping up with the 2.8 project (me), it will be hard to get enough visibility from those who do know the answer to update it. I'm not sure if "duplicate questions" like this has already been addressed on Meta, but it might be worth discussing there as "How to do X in 2.8?" is a common question now.

Comment: IMO related to the version tag chestnut. Rather than a version tag the version is being  tagged in the title. A whole new question and answer for what is a one character change seems a bit OTT.  Version tags for answers would be great. Edited your original answer with such.  I see your point, would not have noticed if not for the new question.

Comment: @JakeD added https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129473/typeerror-element-wise-multiplication-not-supported-between-matrix-and-vect to catch this one.