# How do I change the axis reference point of an object?

Tags: axis

I wanted to create a cone, but when I changed its dimensions, It randomly put the axis reference point at a weird location that makes the positioning of the object (using the numerical location tool) a bit tricky.

[image: cone local axis reference point]

So I'd like to put the cone's local axis reference point at a more comfortable location, like the center of the circle base. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Blender doesn't randomly change the origin.  Chances are you transformed in edit mode.  Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42110/15543

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the object's origin to the center of the circular base.

Go into Edit Mode (Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>). In edit mode you can select vertices, edges or faces. To switch the mode to vertices, or edges or faces hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>. Select the one that's convenient for you.

The goal is to have the center vertex on the circular base selected or a loop of edges around the circular base, or all the faces of the circular base. Whichever's center point is at the center of the circular base. Now set cursor position to selected. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. Select cursor to selected. Now exit out of edit mode. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Now set the origin to 3D cursor. Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. Set origin to 3D cursor. Now you can position the object in reference to the new object origin. Done. :-)