# Finding middle of relative bounding box

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the middle of a (2D) bounding box around an object (the dotted line on the picture). But I don't know how to get the extreme values of the object from this perspective. Would like to make a script that finds it for multiple objects and changes the origin to that place.

[image: Screenshot of the object]

Comment: Where, in depth, (view Z) would you want put the origin of the object?  Is this OK from an orthographic view only, or do you want the bounding rectangle to fit  a _perspective_ projection on to the viewing plane?

Comment: Looks to me like the global bounding box. eg apply rotation and scale to the object and does the newly oriented mesh bounding box match result desired?.  If a number of objects share that mesh with different orientations then changing the origin will affect them all.  Same method as script  here, (adjusted to center of bbox) using the global  method https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42110/15543