# Set origin to Matrix_world bottom center of Lego bricks's bound box

Tags: objects

I have a lego 3D objects, in blender 2.92.0. And I would to set the origin to Matrix_world bottom center of Lego bricks's bound box, then set all bricks to z = 0.

I am a newbie in blender, so I'm trying run the code from [batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/set-origin-to-bottom-center-of-multiple-objects) .

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector


def origin_to_bottom(ob, matrix=Matrix()):
    me = ob.data
    mw = ob.matrix_world
    local_verts = [matrix @ Vector(v[:]) for v in ob.bound_box]
    o = sum(local_verts, Vector()) / 8
    o.z = min(v.z for v in local_verts)
    o = matrix.inverted() @ o
    me.transform(Matrix.Translation(-o))

    mw.translation = mw @ o

for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if o.type == 'MESH':
        origin_to_bottom(o)
        #origin_to_bottom(o, matrix=o.matrix_world) # global
```

and this code:

```
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
import numpy as np

def origin_to_bottom(ob, matrix=Matrix(), use_verts=False):
    me = ob.data
    mw = ob.matrix_world
    if use_verts:
        data = (v.co for v in me.vertices)
    else:
        data = (Vector(v) for v in ob.bound_box)


    coords = np.array([matrix @ v for v in data])
    z = coords.T[2]
    mins = np.take(coords, np.where(z == z.min())[0], axis=0)

    o = Vector(np.mean(mins, axis=0))
    o = matrix.inverted() @ o
    me.transform(Matrix.Translation(-o))

    mw.translation = mw @ o
```

[image]

It's looking like something is wrong, but I can't find out the reason. So, what can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

guys. I get the answer about the question. Thanks for the help from [Martynas Žiemys](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/set-origin-to-bottom-center-of-multiple-objects#answer-175325)

this is the code:

```
def origin_to_bottom(ob):
if ob.mode != 'OBJECT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=True)

d = ob.data
m = ob.matrix_world

bounds_center = (sum((m @ Vector(b) for b in ob.bound_box), Vector()))/8
difference = m.translation - bounds_center
local_difference = difference @ m
for v in d.vertices:
    v.co += local_difference
    m.translation -= difference                   

difference = Vector((0,0,0))
bound = min((m @ v.co).z for v in d.vertices)
difference.z = m.translation.z - bound

local_difference = difference @ m
for v in d.vertices:
    v.co += local_difference
    m.translation -= difference
```